# PHP,MySQL:how to insert/update changing html content into MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a div which value is changed in `tyiping...` on typing in textarea and when stopped typing its value again changed to `no typing` or maybe its empty.

how can I put its changing value into mysql table? or update?

any help would b appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn ajax requests...

By ajax I mean not only ajax. To start learning ajax you must know some jQuery.

Here are some tutorials:
[Bucky's Room](https://buckysroom.org/videos.php?cat=32)

Basicly get the value of the div you change while typing and send it to the database by ajax.

Comment: Or store it in Html5 local Storage.